# Should we post an identical answer if we provide different (maybe better) research?

Tags: discussion

I read an answer to a single word request question. It was exactly what the OP had asked, but the answer provides only an article about the single word, no actual definition from a dictionary, or a resource that actually explains it clearly proving his choice to be the right one.

Would I be entitled to give the same answer with different research, or this is a "no go"?

Comment: What about tell the user to add a dictionary definition, if the word suggested is the correct one? This is more an issue of fair play rather than hard rules.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. He definitely found the spot on term, he should be rewarded for it.

Answer (score 3):

New answers should contribute something significant to the existing set of answers, not just a dictionary definition. Comments are more appropriate for offering constructive criticism on how to improve an answer.

Editing to add a citation to support an answer could also be appropriate. The author can roll it back or improve upon it if they choose, but some people are touchy about edits.

Comment: This is what I did, I left a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/557111/407211). But they said that they felt their source was fine. So I left it at that.

Comment: @fev For that particular answer, I think showing it used in context is more useful than a dictionary definition. Presumably the ELU audience is fluent enough to look it up themselves if they don’t think it’s correct. Most members here will know the meaning of a suggestion unless it’s archaic or very rarely used. It can be tricky sometimes to be active on both ELU and ELL. For a word request on ELU, a dictionary definition isn’t as helpful as showing the word used in context conveying the exact sense that was asked for.